# Htaccess Rewrite Pretty URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

there's probably a very simple answer to my question, but after hours of browsing I still haven't found a solution, so thank you very much for all your help. Perhaps I should mention that I'm using a subdomain with Bluehost (multiple domains on the same account).

I would like to rewrite: **www.example.com/myfolder**
to **www.example.com/index.php?s=myfolder**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

- example.com/abcd  -> works
- example.com/abcd/ -> works but destroys my picture URLs
- example.com/abcd/index.php  -> doesn't work (redirects me
  to main page)

Thank you very much for your help.
Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rewrite to index, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

And for css, scripts, or pictures, use absolutes links (which begin with `/` or `http://...`) or add `<base href="/">` in html head.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

and: [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /picture.php?id=$1